# If $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$ are two topologies, can we defined $\mathcal T\cup \mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T\cap \mathcal S$ on $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a topology space, and $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$ two topology on $X$. I would define $\mathcal T\cap \mathcal S$ the thinest topology included in $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T\cup\mathcal S$ being the coarser topology that contain $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$.

Obviously, each topology is contains in the discrete topology, and all topology contain the coarser topology, but is there any way to construct $\mathcal T\cup \mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T\cap \mathcal S$.

For $\mathcal T\cup \mathcal S$, I would do set

$$\left\lbrace\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal I}U_i\cap V_i\mid U_i\in \mathcal T,V_j\in \mathcal S\right\rbrace.$$
This look to be a topology, no ? And for $\mathcal T\cap \mathcal S$, I have no idea... but may be it's not possible ?

Comment: Notice $T \cap S$ is a topology while $T \cup S$ will not be in general, the most natural way to define $T \cup S$ as a topology would be to say that $T \cup S$ is the smallest topology that contains $T \cup S$ (and then change $T \cup S$ to something else to prevent ambiguity, such as $T \vee S$ say).

Comment: $\mathcal T\cap \mathcal S$ is just the set theory intersection. But $\mathcal T\cup \mathcal S$ is not the set theoretic union, but yes, you can find a smallest topology that contains the two.

Comment: You essentially get that the ordered set of topologies is a lattice.  It can be seen as a complete lattice, I believe. Not sure if it is a distributive lattice.

Comment: @WillM.: Can we construct it rigorously ? (not only say that it's the smallest topology that contain $T\cup S$).

Comment: I don't know what "construct rigorously" can possibly mean and how "is the smallest topology that contains $T \cup S$ is not rigorous? Maybe you did not realise, but the intersection of topologies is a topology (regardless of how many topologies you intersect, but at least one). Thus, the smallest topology that contains $T \cup S$ _signifies_ the intersection of all topologies containing $T \cup S.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathcal T \cap \mathcal S$ you can use the set-theoretic intersection. i.e.

$\mathcal T \cap \mathcal S =\{U: U\in \mathcal T \text{and} \ U\in \mathcal S \}$. Then clearly you can see this is the largest topology which lies inside both topologies.

$\mathcal T \cup \mathcal S$ set $\mathcal B=\{U: U\in \mathcal T \text{or} \ U\in \mathcal S \}$. Then $\mathcal B$ is a subbase for the smallest topology which contains both topologies, and this gives the topology you describe.

Note that both facts generalise to arbitary sups and infs.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $\mathcal{T} \cup \mathcal{S}$ is misleading imo, since a topology is by definition a subset of the powerset, so the union of two such sets is already defined.

Regarding the intersection of two (in fact arbitrary intersections of) topologies (by which I mean the intersection of the subsets of the powerset) note that all the axioms are satisfied, since they are satisfied in all topologies involved.

The coarsest topology containing given two topologies may be defined as the intersection of all topologies containing $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{S}$. Indeed, one can show that this is explicitly given by your definition.